# How to do an Apache sub-request with PHP?

Tags: php, include

I am trying to properly display an error document using a PHP function `virtual()` to users with a "not found" page if a condition is met. This is what I wrote on the script:

```
// if condition is met
virtual('/var/www/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var');
```

Somehow, a blank page is shown and this is the warning I received:

> PHP Warning:  virtual(): Unable to include
>   '/var/www/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var' - request execution failed in
>   /var/www/html/test on line 100

I have checked that the following are being done:

1. In php.ini, `include_path = ".:/var/www/error"`
2. In httpd.conf,

   ```
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
   <IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
     Options +Includes
     AddOutputFilter Includes html
     AddHandler type-map var
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
   </IfModule>
   </IfModule>
   ```
3. Apache has read access to the error folder and files.

What could be causing the warning and how to solve this problem?

Comment: why not a regular 404 page and header location?

Comment: @Dagon, because I want that page to show the 404 error instead of doing a redirect.

Comment: your question says "redirect users" guess i'm just confused.

Comment: @Dagon, my apologies. I will revise that now.

Comment: ok, then why not just use an include?

Comment: @Dagon, because the header and footer for the `.var` file are included with `<!--#include virtual...-->`, so PHP will not parse properly using `include`, returning gibberish instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing root folder from virtual:

```
virtual('/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var');
```

Comment: Tentative +1. I have not used `virtual` myself so far, but looking at the documentation it does seem like the *URL path* is required, not the *file path*. Which makes sense, since it's an *Apache* sub-request.

Comment: You are great. It works! Does anyone of you know how to inject the `var="REDIRECT_STATUS"` into this sub-request? It is showing none instead of 404. Thanks!